# How do a set the value of a google tag manager constant variable in a custom html tag?

Tags: google-tag-manager

```
<script>
  {{MyVarCustomGTMConstant}} = 'Value Set by me';
</script>
```

---

In the above code, I have set up a variable in Google Tag Manager as type constant.

Is this the right way to have global variable I can pass back to tags that fire later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition a constant is a value that cannot be changed by the program during normal execution. As such you cannot change it in your custom HTML tag.

If you need to set variables during execution you can use global JS variable or dataLayer variables instead.

Useful links:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_(computer_programming)
https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/variable-guide-google-tag-manager/#10-constant

Comment: Thanks Matus, You are right... that is the intention of the constant... Where my block was in thinking through javascript and type script, I can indeed update a const type variable.  But the way it is working in GTM, it seems that I can't.  Thank you.  I agree,  the JS variable or dataLayer would be better just take more time to implement.  Once again... Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The correct methodology is to:

*1*: Create a constant variable. Let's call it `Constant X` and the value is `Value Set by me`.

*2*: In the tag where you want to use the constant, you refer to the constant with `{{Constant X}}`.

For example if you have a Custom HTML tag that needs to refer to the constant, you would define the tag as:

```
<script>
  alert("{{Constant X}}");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're wanting to set the value of a GTM variable inside a GTM tag, but if that's what you're aiming for, then you'll need to change your GTM variable to be a dataLayer variable and then push your value to the dataLayer in your GTM tag.  A little more context would help, though.

So your `MyVarCustomGTMConstant` variable would look like this

**Variable Type**: Data Layer Variable

**Data Layer Variable Name**: MyVarCustomGTMConstant

Then, for your Custom HTML GTM tag:

```
<script>
var dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
dataLayer.push({'MyVarCustomGTMConstant':'your new value here'});
</script>
```

That will allow you to set the value of a GTM variable from within GTM.  Now, if you actually want to use the dataLayer push, you'll need to also send an event to create triggers from.  So the above script would look more like this:

```
<script>
var dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
dataLayer.push({
   'event':'friendly-event-name',
   'MyVarCustomGTMConstant':'your new value here'
});
</script>
```